# Automate passive scan for OWASP ZAP as proxy for Node.js HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, docker, http-proxy, owasp, zap

I know I can run the `zap-baseline.py` as Docker container `docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://my_website.org` agains **a website**. I think this is both:

- running a spider on an hypothetical website serving on https://my_website.org (how to disable this given that URL is just a REST API?)
- running the passive scanner

I can see some nice output e.g.:

```
WARN-NEW: Strict-Transport-Security Header Not Set [10035] x 4 
        https://my_website.org/ (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/robots.txt (404 Not Found)
        https://my_website.org (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/sitemap.xml (404 Not Found)
WARN-NEW: Server Leaks Information via "X-Powered-By" HTTP Response Header Field(s) [10037] x 4 
        https://my_website.org/ (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/robots.txt (404 Not Found)
        https://my_website.org (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/sitemap.xml (404 Not Found)
WARN-NEW: Cookie Without SameSite Attribute [10054] x 6 
        https://my_website.org/ (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/ (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/robots.txt (404 Not Found)
        https://my_website.org/robots.txt (404 Not Found)
        https://my_website.org (204 No Content)
WARN-NEW: Cross-Domain Misconfiguration [10098] x 4 
        https://my_website.org/ (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/robots.txt (404 Not Found)
        https://my_website.org (204 No Content)
        https://my_website.org/sitemap.xml (404 Not Found)
```

I know I can use the standalone app ZAP as a GUI to act as a proxy for some Node.js code that is performing HTTP requests while testing my **REST API**. This Node.js code is using Mocha, Chai and Axios to run lots of integration tests against https://example.org, the command: `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' proxychains4 npm run my-integration-test`. Some context:

- I've setup `/etc/proxychains.conf` adding `http 127.0.0.1 8080` so it will use ZAP as the proxy.
- I've added `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'` so Node.js accepts self-singed TLS certificates due to ZAP acting as Man In The Middle between the DNS entry for `example.org` and my Node.js code.

I can see the "Alerts" tab in ZAP is showing something similar to the output of the Docker container:

[image]

How do I export those Alerts in the ZAP GUI to use them with the Docker container and `zap-baseline.py` or similar scripts for passive scanning? If I click the "Export" button I just get a CSV file - nothing the Docker script could parse.

I am trying to automate this so I can then use the exit code of the docker command in a `Makefile` target to be used in a Continuous Integration environment.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. The ZAP baseline scan runs in docker and will report any issue it finds. The ZAP Desktop is a GUI that reports any issues found. They use the same underlying code. If you want to find the issues in a CI environemnt then use the docker option. You dont need to export the alerts from the desktop to pass them to docker - the baseline scan will find them itself...

Comment: The baseline scan is not finding anything. I guess the problem is that the docker command I got working is against a random website, but what I need is to intercept the HTTP calls of my Node.js integration tests against a REST API. So what I see in the GUI (running as a proxy) should be seen in the docker command. Is there a way to run that docker thing as a proxy?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to specify the port and make sure its accessible outside of the docker contain. TBH the ZAP User Group is a better place for this sort of question: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users

Comment: I subscribed to that group, but I am not allowed to post messages or reply to existing messages.

Comment: Looks like you m,anaged it :) For ref this is the thread: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/5UzXKbXqMFY/m/Mg-NaY6MAgAJ